# Get the keys with the biggest values from a hashmap?

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a `HashMap` defined like this...

```
HashMap<String,Integer> uniqueNames = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
```

It stores a name, and the occurence of that name. For example...

```
uniqueNames.put("lastname",42);
```

How can I get the name with the highest occurrence?

For some more information, I'm working with a binary search tree of "people", storing the unique names and frequencies in a `HashMap`. What I want to do is to print the most common last names, and someone told me to use `HashMap` as I wanted to store a `String` together with an `Integer`. Maybe I should use a class to store the name and frequency instead? Could someone please offer some suggestions.

Answer (score 15):

If you have to use a HashMap, then the simplest way is probabably just to loop through the Map looking for the maximum

```
Entry<String,Integer> maxEntry = null;

for(Entry<String,Integer> entry : uniqueNames.entrySet()) {
    if (maxEntry == null || entry.getValue() > maxEntry.getValue()) {
        maxEntry = entry;
    }
}
// maxEntry should now contain the maximum,
```

Answer (score 2):

Most obvious, now allowing for multiple with largest occurrence value:

```
Integer largestVal = null;
List<Entry<String, Integer>> largestList = new ArrayList<Entry<String, Integer>>();
for (Entry<String, Integer> i : uniqueNames.entrySet()){
     if (largestVal == null || largestVal  < i.getValue()){
         largestVal = i.getValue();
         largestList .clear();
         largestList .add(i);
     }else if (largestVal == i.getValue()){
         largestList .add(i);
     }
}
```

Another option would be to use Guava's BiMap.

```
BiMap<String, Integer> uniqueNames = ...;
List<Integer> values = Lists.newArrayList(uniqueNames.values());
Collections.sort(values);
String name = uniqueNames.inverse().get(values.get(0));
```

Comment: Using your first method, how could I then, having the number of the most common lastname, find the lastnames that occurs that many times?

I'll look into the other method, thanks.

Comment: The point is that you have the **Entry** which contains **both** the name and count with the highest count.

Comment: What if there's more than one such entry? Save them in an array?

Comment: How do you mean? If there are multiple names with the same occurrence count?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of going about this actually.

If you are going to be doing this frequently, I would actually suggest storing the mapping in reverse, where the key is the number of times a name has appeared, and the value is a list of names which appeared that many times. I would also use a HashMap to perform the lookups in the other direction as well.

```
TreeMap <Integer, ArrayList <String>> sortedOccurrenceMap =
               new TreeMap <Integer, ArrayList <String>> ();
HashMap <String, Integer> lastNames = new HashMap <String, Integer> ();
boolean insertIntoMap(String key) {
    if (lastNames.containsKey(key)) {
        int count = lastNames.get(key);
        lastNames.put(key, count + 1);

        //definitely in the other map
        ArrayList <String> names = sortedOccurrenceMap.get(count);
        names.remove(key);
        if(!sortedOccurrenceMap.contains(count+1))
            sortedOccurrenceMap.put(count+1, new ArrayList<String>());
        sortedOccurrenceMap.get(count+1).add(key);
    }
    else {
        lastNames.put(key, 1);
        if(!sortedOccurrenceMap.contains(1))
            sortedOccurrenceMap.put(1, new ArrayList<String>());
        sortedOccurrenceMap.get(1).add(key);
    }
}
```

Something similar for deleting...

And finally, for your search:

```
ArrayList <String> maxOccurrences() {
    return sortedOccurrenceMap.pollLastEntry().getValue();
}
```

Returns the List of names that have the max occurrences.

If you do it this way, the searching can be done in O(log n) but the space requirements increase (only by a constant factor though).

If space is an issue, or performance isn't a problem, simply iterate through the uniqueNames.keySet and keep track of the max.

Comment: What if there are more than one lastname occuring X times, when X is the biggest frequency?

Comment: I updated the response with code and I think you will understand. Not too much space is taken, since almost all things are pointers anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want something a bit like a `SortedMap` but one sorted on the value, not the key. I don't think such a thing exists in the standard API.

It might be better to create a Frequency class and store instances in a `SortedSet` instead.

```
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

public class Frequency implements Comparable<Frequency> {

  private String name;
  private int freq;

  public Frequency(String name, int freq) {
    this.name = name;
    this.freq = freq;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Set<Frequency> set = new TreeSet<Frequency>();

    set.add(new Frequency("fred", 1));
    set.add(new Frequency("bob", 5));
    set.add(new Frequency("jim", 10));
    set.add(new Frequency("bert", 4));
    set.add(new Frequency("art", 3));
    set.add(new Frequency("homer", 5));

    for (Frequency f : set) {
      System.out.println(f);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o == null) return false;
    if (o.getClass().isAssignableFrom(Frequency.class)) {
      Frequency other = (Frequency)o;
      return other.freq == this.freq && other.name.equals(this.name);
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  @Override
  public int compareTo(Frequency other) {
    if (freq == other.freq) {
      return name.compareTo(other.name);
    } else {
      return freq - other.freq;
    }
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return name + ":" + freq;
  }

}
```

Output:

> fred:1
>   art:3
>   bert:4
>   bob:5
>   homer:5
>   jim:10

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> list= new ArrayList<String>();
HashMap<String, Integer> map=new HashMap<String,Integer>();

for(String string: list)
{
 if(map.containsKey(string))
 {
     map.put(string, map.get(string)+1);
 }
 else {
    map.put(string, 1);
}
}


Entry<String,Integer> maxEntry = null;

for(Entry<String,Integer> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    if (maxEntry == null || entry.getValue() > maxEntry.getValue()) {
        maxEntry = entry;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the value you can go for this. In this example I had to get the
maximum frequency of a number among an array of 'n' numbers

```
 {
   int n = sc.nextInt();
   int arr[] = new int[n];
   int freq = 1;
   int i;
   Map<Integer,Integer> myMap = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
   
   for(i=0;i<n;i++){
       
       arr[i] = sc.nextInt();
       if(!myMap.containsKey(arr[i])){
           
           myMap.put(arr[i],freq);
 
       }
       else
           {
           
           myMap.put(arr[i],(myMap.get(arr[i])+1));
           
       }
           
   }
  
  int max = 0; 
  for(i=0;i<n;i++){
      
       if(myMap.get(arr[i])>max)    
       max = myMap.get(arr[i]);
           
  }
   System.out.println(max);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my approach.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

public class FindWordCounter {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    try {

        System.out.println("Enter the sentence: ");
        String sentence = bufferedReader.readLine();
        FindWordCounter.countWord(sentence);

    }   catch (IOException e) {

        System.out.println(e);

    }
}

public static void countWord(String sentence) {

    Map<String, Integer> hashMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    String[] word = sentence.toLowerCase().split(" ");

    for (int i=0; i<word.length; i++) {

        if (hashMap.containsKey(word[i])) {

            int count = hashMap.get(word[i]);
            hashMap.put(word[i], count + 1);

        }
        else {
            hashMap.put(word[i], 1);
        }
    }

    Entry<String,Integer> maxCount = null;

    for(Entry<String,Integer> entry : hashMap.entrySet()) {

        if (maxCount == null || entry.getValue() > maxCount.getValue()) {
            maxCount = entry;

        }
    }

    System.out.println("The word with maximum occurence is: " + maxCount.getKey() 
                            + " and the number of occurence is: " + maxCount.getValue());
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

1.Try this it may help.

```
static <K, V> List<K> getAllKeysForValue(Map<K, V> mapOfWords, V value) 
{
    List<K> listOfKeys = null;

    //Check if Map contains the given value
    if(mapOfWords.containsValue(value))
    {
        // Create an Empty List
        listOfKeys = new ArrayList<>();

        // Iterate over each entry of map using entrySet
        for (Map.Entry<K, V> entry : mapOfWords.entrySet()) 
        {
            // Check if value matches with given value
            if (entry.getValue().equals(value))
            {
                // Store the key from entry to the list
                listOfKeys.add(entry.getKey());
            }
        }
    }
    // Return the list of keys whose value matches with given value.
    return listOfKeys;  
}
```