# Java - Choose a random value from a HashMap but one with the highest integer assigned

Tags: java

I want to choose a random value from a HashMap but it has to have the highest value assigned to it.
For example, I want to choose a random person from this list but only if they have the most "tickets" per say. 
Example:

- John - 10
- Alex - 10
- David - 5
- Alan - 10

From this list, I want to choose a random person with the most "tickets." So in this case, it would be from John, Alex or Alan.

So far I have this:

`HashMap<UUID, Integer> tickets = new HashMap<UUID, Integer>();`

Where the UUID would be the names of people in the above example and Integer would be their ticket amount.

Comment: You might benefit from taking a look at this post here, seems extremely relevant. Once you have all people with the highest integer, you can just pick a random one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7498751/get-the-keys-with-the-biggest-values-from-a-hashmap.

Comment: @LaurentiuL. the question is phrased badly. I think what OP means is: if there is more than one person with maximal number of tickets, select one of them randomly and return him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a map of type `Map<Integer, List<UUID>>`. Use [`SortedMap<K, V>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html), and your keys will be ordered by their natural ordering by default. Since you are using `Integer` for the key, you don't need any special logic to enforce ordering.

Then you just need to generate a random number between 0 and the `list.size() - 1` for the highest key in the map. To get the highest key, you will need to construct a [`TreeSet<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html) instance from your map's `keySet`. You can then use `last()` to get the highest key, and then you can retrieve the list of UUIDs for that key.

You can easily create a sorted map like so:

```
Map<Integer, List<UUID>> map = new SortedMap<>();
```

Then you just need to create a `TreeSet<Integer>` instance from your `keySet` like this:

```
TreeSet<Integer> sortedKeySet = new TreeSet<>(map.keySet());
```

After that, you can get the highest key, and the associated list of UUIDs like so:

```
Integer highestKey = sortedKeySet.last();
List<UUID> usersWithHigestKey = map.get(highestKey);
```

Then you just need to generate a random number between `0` and `usersWithHighestKey.size()` (exclusive) to get a random user with the highest value.

Comment: To get the item corresponding to the highest key you can just use something like `List<UUID> highestValueList = myMap.get(myMap.lastKey());` (although you should make sure that the map isn't empty first)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but I'm not as advanced as that and I haven't experienced SortedMaps or NavigableSets yet. If you could show me an example, it would be appreciated.

Comment: @Ally to use a sorted map you would do something like this assuming you already have your `tickets` map populated with data: `SortedMap<Integer, List<UUID>> sortedTickets = new TreeMap<>(); for (Entry<UUID, Integer> entry : tickets.entrySet()) {List<UUID> list = sortedTickets.get(entry.getValue()); if (list == null) {list = new ArrayList<>(); sortedTickets.put(entry.getValue(), list);} list.add(entry.getKey());} List<UUID> highestValList = sortedTickets.get(sortedTickets.lastKey()); UUID random = highestValList.get((int)(Math.random() * highestValList.size()));`

Comment: @Ally take a look at my edit. You can use ` TreeSet<T>` (it implements both `SortedSet<T>` and `NavigableSet<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be solved with a [Reservoir Sampling algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling). You can iterate over the rows with highest ticket number and pick the current item with prob 1/n where n is the count of items you iterated over before, so you pick the first because it is 1/1 = 100%, but you cointinue iterating, then you have 1/2=50% prob of picking the second one, overriting the one you had before (the first or the second), then you have 1/3 of chances of picking the third and so on.

But you have some rows mixed, ones with max value and others with lower values and you don't know at first what is the max but you can calculate it on a single loop.

Pseudocode:

```
n = 0;
max = -1;
uuid = null;

for (k, v: entries) {
  if (v > max) {
    // Reset to new max, we pick that one, prob = 1/1 = 100%
    // Previous work is useless as the value of max was not the real max
    max = v;
    n = 1;
    uuid = k;
  } else if (v == max) {
    // This item's value is equal to current max so there is a chance we pick it
    // We pick this with prob 1/n
    n = n + 1;
    if (randomFloatFrom0To1() < 1/n) {
      uuid = k;
    }
  } else {
    // This sample is not interesting
  }
}
//uuid at this point should be random among the ones with v = max
```

I think that is what you need. Single loop, O(n)

The input may be a map or any other sequence of key/value pairs.

`randomFloatFrom0To1()` may be implemented in java as:

```
java.util.Random r = new java.util.Random();
// ...
r.nextFloat() // <-- This returns random float between 0 and 1
```

You can use a random integer too:

```
if (r.nextInteger(n) == 0) { // <-- Same probability, 1/n
  //...
```

Comment: If you construct your map to be sorted in the first place, you can achieve insertion of new keys in `O(log n)` time, and retrieve the maximum key in constant time; much better than `O(n)`.

Comment: @VivinPaliath you are assuming I am using a map. To construct a map you need O(n) as you need to process the n elements (put them on the map) plus the map processing (that is O(log n) for every element, so O(n log n)). With my approach you are done, you don't need the map, just any input of tuples and a single loop over them.

Comment: @usser270349. Creation of the map would be `nlogn`, but then retrieval of max-key is `O(1)` after that. You are proposing `O(n)` creation and then `O(n)` retrieval every time.

Comment: @VivinPaliath this algorithm does not need any map. If the input is a HashMap it can iterate it's entryset but if it is any other input, any sequence of pairs, it does not need to build a map first.

Comment: I agree, but even if you don't factor in map-construction into the final complexity, you're still performing `O(n)` lookup. This could be fine if you don't know what kind of collection you are getting, and if you don't know what sort of ordering it has. But the point here is that the OP can use a collection that addresses his use-case **exactly** and use behavior from those collections to accomplish what he wants. Hence there is no need to create a special-purpose method simply to find the maximum key; a `SortedSet` and a `TreeMap` will do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution would be to build a new array that only contains elements that are equal to the maximum amount of "tickets" that a person has. Then use a random number generator to select an element out of that array (by randomly generating a number between 0 and list.length-1)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 8, you can solve the problem with streams and lambdas:

```
private static final Random R = new Random();

public static String getRandomMax(HashMap<String, Integer> data)
{
    if ((null == data) || data.isEmpty()) {
        return (null);
    }

    int max = data.values().stream().max(Integer::max).get();

    Predicate<String> reducer = name -> { return (data.get(name) == max); };

    List<String> names = data.keySet()
                             .stream()
                             .filter(reducer)
                             .collect(Collectors.toList());

    if (1 == names.size()) {
        return (names.get(0));
    }
    int idx = R.nextInt(names.size());
    return (names.get(idx));
}
```