# choose a random value from a inverse weigthed map

Tags: java, random

I'm using a Map with eligible words for a hangman game I'm developing. The Integer in the Map stores the times a word has been chosen, so in the beginning the Map looks like this:

```
alabanza 0
esperanza 0
comunal 0
aprender 0
....
```

After some plays, the Map would look like this

```
alabanza 3
esperanza 4
comunal 3
aprender 1
....
```

I'd like  to choose the next word randomly but having the less chosen word a bigger probability of been chosen.

I've read [Java - Choose a random value from a HashMap but one with the highest integer assigned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30737475/java-choose-a-random-value-from-a-hashmap-but-one-with-the-highest-integer-ass) but it's the opposite case.

I''ve also thought I could use a list with repeated words (the more times a word appears in the list, the more the probabilities of been chosen) but I've only managed to get to this:

```
int numberOfWords=wordList.size(); //The Map
List<String> repeatedWords=new ArrayList<>();
for (Map.Entry<String,Integer> entry : wordList.entrySet()) {
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfWords-entry.getValue(); i++) {
        repeatedWords.add(entry.getKey());
    }
}
Collections.shuffle(repeatedWords);  //Should it be get(Random)?
String chosenWord=repeatedWords.get(0);
```

I think this fails when the amount of words chosen equals the amount of words.

### Edit

Finally there's a problem with the probability of each word once they have different numbers. I've changed the point of view so I first put a probability of 1000 (It could be any number) and every time I choose a word, I reduce the probability a certain amount (let's say, 20%), so I use:

```
wordList.put(chosen,(int)(wordList.get(chosen)*0.8)+1);
```

After that I choose the word with the recipe Lajos Arpad or Ahmad Shahwan gave.
If the game were to be played many many times, all the probabilities would tend to 1, but that's not my case.

Thanks all who answered.

Comment: In your examples (0, 0, 0, 0) (3, 4, 3, 1), what probability do you want for each entry to be picked ?

Comment: That's a problem. I can't a "natural" way to define that probability

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Random;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Map<String, Integer> wordList = new HashMap<>();
        wordList.put("alabanza", 3);
        wordList.put("esperanza", 4);
        wordList.put("comunal", 3);
        wordList.put("aprender", 1);

        Map<String, Integer> results = new HashMap<>(4);
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            String name = randomize(wordList);
            Integer old = results.getOrDefault(name, 0);
            results.put(name, old + 1);
        }

        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> e : results.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(e.getKey() + "\t" + e.getValue());
        }
    }

    private static String randomize(Map<String, Integer> wordList) {
        final Integer sum = wordList.values().stream().reduce(Integer::sum).orElse(0);
        final int grandSum = (wordList.size() - 1) * sum;
        final int random = new Random().nextInt(grandSum + 1);

        int index = 0;
        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> e: wordList.entrySet()) {
            index += (sum - e.getValue());
            if (index >= random) {
                return e.getKey();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Out put is the times a name was chosen over 100 trial:

`aprender    37
alabanza    25
comunal     23
esperanza   15`

You can try it yourself [here](https://www.jdoodle.com/embed/v0/vYJ).

Comment: This works as it's supossed to do. I've finally chosen another way to do it but thanks

Answer (score 0):

I won't provide exact code, but basic idea.

1. Iterate over `wordList.values()` to find the maximum weight `M` and sum of weights `S`.
2. Now let each word `w` have likelihood (like probability, but they don't have to sum to 1) to be chosen `M + 1 - wordList.get(w)`, so a word with weight `1` is `M` times more likely to be chosen than a word with weight `M`.
3. The sum of likelihoods will be `(M + 1) * wordList.size() - S` (that's why we need `S`). Pick a random number `R` between 0 and this sum.
4. Iterate over `wordList.entrySet()`, summing likelihoods as you go. When the sum passes `R`, that's the word you want.

Comment: Maybe there's a problem with w at the beginning when no word has been chosen (all the weights are zero). Should I change it to 1, for example and decrease the weigth as words are chosen, with doubles, dividing by 2 each time a word has been chosen?

Comment: It looks to me like everything works at the beginning: both `M` and `S` are 0, so each word gets likelihood 1 and sum of likelihoods is `wordList.size()`.

Comment: Another simple way would be to make likelihood for `w` `1 / (wordList.get(w) + 1)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your map values are your weights.

You need to pick an integer lower than the weights sum.

You pick each String entry, with its weight. When the weight sum passes the random integer, you are on THE String.

This will give you :

```
public static void main(String ... args){
    Map<String, Integer> wordList = new HashMap<>();
    wordList.put("foo", 4);
    wordList.put("foo2", 2);
    wordList.put("foo3", 7);

    System.out.println(randomWithWeight(wordList));
}

public static String randomWithWeight(Map<String, Integer> weightedWordList) {
    int sum = weightedWordList.values().stream().collect(Collectors.summingInt(Integer::intValue));

    int random = new Random().nextInt(sum);
    int i = 0;
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> e : weightedWordList.entrySet()){
        i += e.getValue();
        if (i > random){
            return e.getKey();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: At first all the Integer values are zero (as none word has been chosen yet) and your method throws an java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bound must be positive because the sum is 0. This is one of the problems I've had.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of simplicity let us suppose that you have an array called `occurrences`, which has `int` elements (you will easily translate this into your data structure).

Now, let's find the maximum value:

```
int max = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < occurrences.length; i++) {
    if (max < occurrences[i]) max = occurrences[i];
}
```

Let's increment it:

```
max++;
```

Now, let's give a weight of `max` to the items which have 0 as value, a weight of `max - 1` to the items which occurred once, and so on (no item will have a weight of 0 since we incremented `max`):

```
int totalWeight = 0;

for (int j = 0; j < occurrences.length; j++) {
    totalWeight += max - occurrences[j];
}
```

Note that all items will have their weight. Now, let's suppose you have a randomized integer, called `r`, where **0 < r <= totalWeight**:

```
int resultIndex = -1;

for (int k = 0; (resultIndex < 0) && k < occurrences.length; k++) {
    if (r <= max - occurrences[k]) resultIndex = k;
    else r -= max - occurrences[k];
}
```

and the result is `occurrences[resultIndex]`