# Java - return the key with the longest ArrayList in Hashmap<Class,ArrayList<Class>>

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I've been trying to modify the code from top answers from a similar question here, but I can't get it to work for arraylist lengths

[Get the keys with the biggest values from a hashmap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7498751/get-the-keys-with-the-biggest-values-from-a-hashmap)

Lets say I have

`HashMap<Customer,ArrayList<Call>> outgoingCalls = new HashMap<Customer,ArrayList<Call>>();`

When the program runs, it stores every call made in the hashmap. I want to run through this hashmap and return the Customer who has made the most calls. I've been trying to modify this code from the link above but I'm completely lost

```
   Entry<Customer,ArrayList<Call> mostCalls = null;

   for(Entry<String,ArrayList<Call> e : outgoingCalls.entrySet()) {
     if (mostCalls == null || e.getValue() > mostCalls.getValue()) {
        mostCalls = e;
```

Comment: `e.getValue()` returns an `ArrayList<Call>`. So does `mostCalls.getValue()`. > (greater than) works for numbers, not collections like `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 5):

Close, but not quite.

```
 Entry<Customer,ArrayList<Call>> mostCalls = null;

 for(Entry<String,ArrayList<Call>> e : outgoingCalls.entrySet()) {
   if (mostCalls == null || e.getValue().size() > mostCalls.getValue().size()) {
      mostCalls = e;
   }
 }
```

Comment: Thanks! One thing I forgot to mention is that I'm getting the `cannot find symbol: Entry` error. I thought that `java.util.*` should be enough to import it, but is there something else I need to do?

Comment: You need to either `import java.util.Map.Entry` or use `Map.Entry` instead of `Entry`.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I still have to work on the code to actually display this, but i'm not getting any compiler errors which i'll take as a good sign.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this out. You will not need any extra imports.

```
int maxSize = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
for(Customer e: outgoingCalls.keySet()) {
    if (maxSize < outgoingCalls.get(e).size()) {
        maxSize = outgoingCalls.get(e).size();
        mostCalls = e;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class T {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Customer> customerList = new ArrayList<Customer>();
    customerList.add(new Customer());
    Collections.sort(customerList, new Comparator<Customer>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Customer c1, Customer c2) {
        return c1.callsMadeByCustomer.size() - c2.callsMadeByCustomer.size();
        }
    });
    System.out.println("Most Calls: " + customerList.get(customerList.size() - 1));
    }
}

class Customer {
    ArrayList<Call> callsMadeByCustomer;

    public Customer() {
        callsMadeByCustomer = new ArrayList<Call>();
    }
}
```

You can even organise it like this. So now callsMadeByCustomer are inside the customer class.